# Retrieve the name of the column from which the values where chosen in C#

Tags: c#

I have a form which has 4 columns say **Col1**,**Col2**,**Col2**,**Col4**...

Each Column has a combo box (**cmb1,cmb2,cmb3,cmb4**) having values ranged from **1 to 3.**

If I select value of **cmb1** as **1**,
**cmb2** as **2**,
**cmb3** as **3**, 
**cmb4** as **2** ....
I need to know which column had 1 as value,2 as value and 3 .

here the result should be like 
**Col1 has 1 value** ,
**Col2 and Col4 has 2 value** and
 **Col3 has 3 value**

Following is my code :

```
if (cmb1 == "1" && cmb2 == "1" && cmb3 == "1" && cmb4 == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4");
                }
                if (cmb1 == "1" && cmb2 == "1" && cmb3 == "1")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Col1,Col2,Col3");
                }
                if (cmb1 == "2" && cmb2 == "2" )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Col1,Col2");
                }
```

This code is too lengthy .Which is the best way with minimum lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the value, then select the column name by Linq.

For display you can use `string.Join()`.

```
var cmb1 = "1";
var cmb2 = "2";
var cmb3 = "3";
var cmb4 = "2";

var selection = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{ 
    {"Col1", cmb1},
    {"Col2", cmb2},
    {"Col3", cmb3},
    {"Col4", cmb4},
};

var result = selection
    .GroupBy(i => i.Value) // Group by your combo box values
    .Select(group =>
        new
        {
            Value = group.Key,
            Columns = group.Select(i => i.Key).ToArray()
        }
    );
foreach (var item in result) // for each value in your combo box
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("Value: {0}, Columns: {1}",
        item.Value,
        string.Join(",", item.Columns)));

    string[] column = item.Columns; // It should store somewhere else, line for demo only
}
```

Comment: I get the result the way I want ,but in the end during the the time of display I want to store each column name into a  string..how can that be?? @Eric

Comment: @TechBrkTru Edit the first parameter in `string.Format()` like `"{1}"`?

Comment: :no no ...I want to store them like `string[] column = new column[4];`  and store each `line` within that after doing the `string.format()` as `"{1}"` @Eric

Comment: @TechBrkTru Sure, you can now use the result for display and further processing, see edit

Answer (score 2):

`ComboBox` has property named `SelectedItem`, you can get the selectedvalue due to `SelectedItem`.And set the `Name` of `Combox`.

```
  List<Combox> comboxs = new List<Combox>;
    comboxs.Add(cmb1);
    comboxs.Add(cmb2);
    comboxs.Add(cmb3);
    comboxs.Add(cmb4);
  foreach(var combox in comboxs){
    Console.WriteLine(combox.Name + "has" + combox.SelectedItem + "value");
  }
```